# How to find odd item in given list of numbers?(PS here odd means different)

Tags: clojure

I have to display the index of the odd items in a given list of numbers.

I tried getting the remainder but I have to divide the given list by `[2 3 5 10]` in order to know which element is odd.

```
(defn odd_one_out [y]
  (println (map #(rem % 2) y)))

(odd_one_out [2 8 9 200 56])
```

I expect the output 9 or index of 9 since it is the only element which  cannot be divided by 2.
The output i am getting is `0 0 1 0 0`

Comment: Drop the `println`. Clojure will print the result at the REPL without it, and you can embed the computation as is in anything you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the number which is uniquely indivisible for given divisors. You could use `group-by` to group the numbers by their divisibility, then find the one(s) that are indivisible by exactly one divisor.

```
(defn odd-one-out [nums divs]
  (->> nums
       (group-by #(map (fn [d] (zero? (mod % d))) divs))
       (some (fn [[div-flags nums']]
               (and (= 1 (count nums'))
                    (= 1 (count (filter true? div-flags)))
                    (first nums'))))))

(odd-one-out [2 8 9 200 56] [2 3 5 10]) ;; => 9

(odd-one-out [2 10 20 60 90] [2 3 5 10]) ;; => 2
```

Comment: what is the use of div-flags?

Comment: (odd-one-out [1 3 6 9 81] [2 3 5 10]);;->nil
this test case fails with this code

Comment: @CoDInGbrO can you explain what/why that should return? There is no number that is uniquely indivisible. `div-flags` and `nums'` are the keys and values of the output of `group-by`. Try removing the `some` to see the intermediate output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extend your current function, you could use `map-indexed`,which will give you this list `([0 0] [1 0] [2 1] [3 0] [4 0])`, which you can then filter to keep only the vectors that have `1` in the second position. This will return the index of the odd character.

```
(defn odd-one-out [y]
  (->> y
       (map #(rem % 2))
       (map-indexed vector)
       (filter #(= 1 (second %)))
       (map first)))

(odd-one-out [2 8 9 200 56])
(2)
```

Even better would be to use the function `odd?` from Clojure's standard library.

```
(->> [2 8 9 200 56]
     (map odd?)
     (map-indexed vector)
     (filter #(second %))
     (map first))
```

Another version using `keep`.

(to return the index)

```
(->> [2 8 9 200 56]
     (map-indexed vector)
     (keep #(when (odd? (second %))
              (first %))))
(2)
```

(to return the value)

```
(->> [2 8 9 200 56]
     (map-indexed vector)
     (keep #(when (odd? (second %))
              (second %))))
(9)
```

Comment: I do not need the index of odd number, i need the index of odd item for example

Comment: If we have a list [ 2 10 20 60 90] then it should compare/divide it with another list [2 3 5 10] and since all the other numbers are divisible by 5,it should return 2 or index of 2.

Comment: Then you are going to properly define your problem.
Why should the list `[2 10 20 60 90]` be checked for divisibility by 5, but the list `[2 8 9 200 56]` for divisitibility by 2?

Comment: well first u have to check with 2 if u find the odd one then return it and if u dont then go on for 3,then 5 and then 10